# AFNetworking background JSON parsing avoid block nesting

Tags: afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I have some networking code with heavy JSON parsing going on. It needs to be done in the background to not block the main thread. The code looks like this :

```
-(void) getSomeDataWithParameters:(...)parameters completion:(void (^)(NSArray *data))completion
{
    NSURLRequest *req = ...
    AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];

    // sometimes I have more requests

    // startOperations is a wrapper on AFHTTPClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:
    // that handles errors and loading views
    [self startOperations:@[op] completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

        // getBgQueue = return dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(getBgQueue(), ^{

            NSArray *data = [MyParserClass parseJSON:op.responseJSON inContext:self.localContext];

            [self.localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                // this is executed on main thread
                if(completion) completion(...);
            }];

        });

    }];
}
```

(AFNetworking 1.x)

The above code works very fine, but it's a pain to setup and write. And often the whole method content is wrapped inside another block to fetch some required data first... basically the blocks just pile up and makes ugly code

I'm using `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` and not individual completion blocks on `AFJSONRequestOperation` because batch completion block would sometimes fire before all individual operations completion blocks... (I also read somewhere that Mattt discouraged doing this)

Any pointers on how to do better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want here, but just like "longcat is long", it's somewhat inherent in the pattern: 'continuation-passing style is continuation-passing style'. If you want to flatten things out a bit, you could make local block variables, but to a certain degree, you're stuck because you need the completion for `-MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion` to close over `data` in order to pass it to the `-getSomeDataWithParameters...` completion, but `data` won't exist until the `-startOperations` completion is executed.

You could probably achieve a less-nested appearance by using a bunch of `__block` variables, and splitting the code into several local blocks, but to me that feels kind of like cutting off your nose to spite your face. This code is readily understandable the way it is.

By the way... I notice that you're closing over `op` in the `-startOperations` completion block. This is fine because you're enqueuing `op` by doing `-startOperations: @[op] ...` but it would arguably be cleaner to get `op` from the `operations` parameter to the completion. I tightened this up as much as seemed reasonable:

```
- (void)getSomeDataWithParameters:(...)parameters completion:(void (^)(NSArray *data))completion
{
    NSURLRequest *req = ...;
    AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];

    [self startOperations:@[op] completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        for (AFJSONRequestOperation *op in operations) {
            dispatch_async(getBgQueue(), ^{
                NSArray *data = [MyParserClass parseJSON:op.responseJSON inContext:self.localContext];
                void (^mrSaveCompletion)(BOOL, NSError*) = completion ? ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) { completion(data); } : nil;
                [self.localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion: mrSaveCompletion];
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

This will fan out each response potentially to a different thread. If you want all responses to execute on a single background thread, just swap the nesting of the `for` loop and the `dispatch_async`.

From there, the only really "superfluous" code is the `dispatch_async`. You could eliminate that by making `-startOperations:...` take a queue parameter where you would pass in the queue you wanted the completion to be called. Maybe like this:

```
- (void)startOperations: (NSArray*)ops completionQueue: (dispatch_queue_t)queue completionBlock: (void (^)(NSArray*))completion
{
    void (^completionWrapper)(NSArray*) = !completion ? nil : ^(NSArray* ops) {
        if (queue)
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{ completion(ops); });
        else
            completion(ops);
    };

    [self startOperations: ops completionBlock: completionWrapper];
}

- (void)getSomeDataWithParameters:(...)parameters completion:(void (^)(NSArray *data))completion
{
    NSURLRequest *req = ...;
    AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
    [self startOperations:@[op] completionQueue: getBgQueue() completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        for (AFJSONRequestOperation *op in operations) {
            NSArray *data = [MyParserClass parseJSON:op.responseJSON inContext:self.localContext];
            void (^mrSaveCompletion)(BOOL, NSError*) = !completion ? nil : ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) { completion(data); };
            [self.localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion: mrSaveCompletion];
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented something similar to `completionQueue` parameter. Quick question : would it be possible to write similar code with only `NSOperation`s/`NSOperationQueue`s and not blocks?